# Cryptic Hour Pyramid!

Tags: story, cryptic-clues

**A pyramid is on fire.**

Being an archaeologist, you went to Egypt to study a very ancient pyramid. While you were on top of it, the pyramid caught fire. It was time to run when you discovered that, every floor had a door. You tried opening the door but to no luck. Looking for a way, you found out that the door had some carvings which you never saw before. Interesting enough, the carvings were cryptic clues.

It was now time to run and save your life. Try figuring your way down.

[image]

> 1. Misdirected tailless beaver state (1)
> 2. First of republican state, monetary unit (2)
> 3. Be a rebel at first, to inverted pub (3)
> 4. Rage in Quarantined (4)
> 5. Full of crows (5)
> 6. Dismantle vampire without I gives improved form (6)
> 7. Scaled down, say (7)

Once you are back, you will discover the reason behind the Pyramid's name.

***Come down and tell me what's in the name.***

Comment: Is the enumeration number of letters?

Comment: @Sid: I think so. The pyramid is the grid.

Comment: Yeah. @M Oehm is right.

Comment: Is 5 a cryptic clue?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil-Yes. Without any indicator. It's a simple def.

Comment: Okay, if you see my answer, is that right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil- That will do just fine. :)

Comment: @Techidiot: If it's "just a simple def", then it's not a cryptic clue. Many of these don't seem to be valid cryptics.

Comment: @Deusovi- I learnt from [here](http://bestforpuzzles.com/cryptic-crossword-tutorial/cryptic-definitions.html) _"Sometimes a cryptic clue will consist only of a definition"_

Comment: Sorry, but if the top of the ancient pyramid catches on fire, considering it's made of sandstone in Egypt, how likely is it that the fire will travel _down_?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **R** is in the name

The answers are:

> 1. **R** - Beaver state is OREGON or OR, misdirected = RO and tailess gives R (Thanks @MOehm)
> 2. **RS** - **R**epublican **S**tates and an abbreviation of the monetary unit rupees.
> 3. **RAB** - **B**e **A** **R**ebel inverted, and un-inverted it's a type of pub.
> 4. **RANT** - (Thanks Sid!) qua**RANT**ined - means rage
> 5. **ROOST** or ROOKY* - (Thanks @Will) nesting place for crows or Rook*  (Crow). Place full of crows is a ROOKY place.*
> 6. **REVAMP** - VAMPIRE minus I anagrammed and means an improved form
> 7. **RESIZED** - Means scaled down

So the pyramid looks like:

> ```
>             
>               R
>              R S
>             R A B
>            R A N T
>           R O O S T    (or R O O K Y)
>          R E V A M P
>         R E S I Z E D
> ```

And

> They all begin with 'R'. R is pronounced like 'hour', hence the name of the pyramid - Cryptic **HOUR** Pyramid.

<sub>* OP's edit</sub>

Comment: Pretty sure 3 is BAR B(e) A R(ebel)

Comment: Should the name of the pyramid be "Rs on fire"? (Well, obviously a homophone of that.)

Comment: @MOehm I asked Techidiot if 'R' is the final answer and he said 'That will do just fine'. Not really sure what that means but oh well

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil- I didn't say that. I said, you have got all the clues right. :) So, just the final one and you are done.

Comment: [A:(r\)] -> Brit (I guess it might get tougher to guess)

Comment: @Techidiot ok. Bit confused here. 7Rs?

Comment: Hour is pronounced as [A:(r\)] in Britain English. i.e. "R"

Comment: @Techidiot can you pop into TSL and explain that to me?

Comment: +1, though "reduced" seems to fit better than "resized". At least that's what I got on my notepad.

Comment: @ymbirtt I originally had that too, but techidiot told me that he intended resized, so I changed it

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer:

1.Misdirected tailless beaver state (1)

> R (Beaver state-Oregon OR, misdirected is RO and tailless gives "R" (Thanks, @M Oehm)

2.First of republican state,monetary unit(2)

> Rs. (First letters of Republican state, definition - Monetary unit)

3.Be a rebel at first, to inverted pub (3)

> Rab (Apparently, it is inverted Bar, which has no definition. Surprising) (First letters of "Be a Rebel")

4. Rage in Quarantined (4)

   > Rant? (Rage is the definition and Rant is present in quarantined?)
5. Full of crows(5)

   > Roost (Nesting place for crows as pointed out by @Beastly Gerbil with the help of @Will)

6.Dismantle vampire without I gives improved form(6)

> Revamp (Removing I from vampire and anagram)

7.Scaled down, say (7)

> Reduced (Jim points it out in the answers, and one which I had arrived independently and was searching for the wordplay, in there)

Now, the pyramid:

> Everything contains "R" in it. The OP asks "What's **in** the name? So, "R" is in the name. (Less than satisfactory, but I can't see anything else)

Comment: your 5 has 6 characters. Sadly makes it so it can't be a murder either per new clue.

Comment: @Sumurai8 that's why I discounted it

Comment: Credit Will with 5, he got it in chat

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Did it..

Answer (score 2):

> REDUCED

fits much better with the final clue

Once you "R" Back.  Feels like a play on words

> Misdirected tailless beave(R) state  (6th letter from the back)
> First of republican state, moneta(R)y unit  (6th letter from the back)
> Be a rebel at first, to inve(R)ted pub  (7th letter from the back)
> Rage in Qua(R)antined  (8th letter from the back)
> Full of c(R)ows  (4th letter from the back)
> Dismantle vampire without I gives improved fo(R)m  (2nd letter from the back)
> Scaled down, say
>
> Looking at the first R from the back of the clue. Though the last clue doesn't have one.
>
> Still perplexed by 'say' though it feels like "RESPOND".

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Can you add an explanation?

Comment: @Jim you should put that in your answer, not a comment

Comment: You may be right, but the clue says "Scaled down, say", which means that scaling down is an example of the answer we look for. Still, reduced works, of course.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Check out our [tour], and, if you're planning on asking anything, our [ask] page! Hope to see you around!

Comment: Thanks for using spoilers. Markup inside spoilers is tricky, though: You must prepend every line in a spoiler with `>!` and empty lines aren't detencted; use two or more spaces at the end of a line or the `<br />` tag to cause a line break. I've editied your post.